# C++ using custom copy constructor when object returned from a function?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class Tree
{
 private:
double height;
string name;

public:
Tree()
{
    cout << "Default constructor of class Tree." << endl;
    height = 0;
    name = "";
}

Tree(double he, string na)
{
    cout << "Parameterized constructor of class Tree." << endl;
    height = he;
    name = na;
}

Tree(Tree &t)
{
    cout << "Customized copy constructor of class Tree." << endl;
    height = t.height;
    name = t.name;
}

void toString()
{
    cout << name << " " << height << endl;
}
};
Tree getTree()
{
Tree t(321, "abc");
return t;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Tree t1(123, "xyz");
Tree t2 = getTree();
t2.toString();

return 0;
}
```

Tree Object returned from function getTree() should be copy to the object t2 using the customized copy constructor, while the compiler complaints "error: no matching function for call to 'Tree::Tree(Tree)'".

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor needs to accept the const version of your object. Change the copy constructor to :

```
Tree(const Tree &t)
{
    cout << "Customized copy constructor of class Tree." << endl;
    height = t.height;
    name = t.name;
}
```

This clears the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but from this page http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/, the copy constructor without "const" should also be a correct signature.

Comment: @JuliaX: it is _a_ correct signature for a copy constructor. But it is not the correct one for your use-case. r-values can't be bound to non-const l-value references

Answer (score -1):

Tree `t2 = getTree()` makes a call to the copy constructor `Tree(Tree &t)`, which accepts a reference to the instance of class Tree, while the function `Tree getTree()` returns an object, and not a reference. The solution to the problem is for the function `Tree getTree()` to return the reference: `Tree& getTree()`.

And just for your information, the copy constructor should accept a `const Tree &`, that solves the problem too. It's a norm to write a copy-constructor like this:

```
Tree(const Tree &t) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Edit: You will probably get a warning that the reference to the local variable is returned, but you can choose to ignore the warning **or** you can change your copy-constructor. Personally, I would change the copy constructor.

Comment: ... And then you returned a reference to a local variable, and using it triggers undefined behaviour.

Comment: Check my edit for that. I said that it returns a reference to a local variable and that I would change the constructor.

Comment: *Choose to ignore the warning* ? That's today's worse suggestion. Using an object past its lifetime is UB, and may (and will eventually) cause anything from seemingly working code to nonsensical execution and random crashes. Do not *ever* ignore warnings.

Comment: I said that he/she **can** choose to ignore the warning, not that he/she **should**. I suggested editting the copy-constructor. Reread my edit carefully.

Comment: Well, he **can** also choose to insert `++*(int*)0;` in there. I probably wouldn't *suggest* it though.

Comment: Of course he can choose and of course I wouldn't suggest it, just like I didn't suggest ignoring the warning.

Answer (score -1):

```
Tree getTree()
{
  Tree t(321, "abc");
  return t;
}
```

The getTree(), here is returning a local object by value. So a temporary object is created (temp objects are const), which means the Copy-Ctor is being passed a const object whereas by definition it is expecting non-const object. Changing the Copy-Ctor parameter to const will fix this issue.

Comment: Can you explain about "temp objects are const"?

Comment: Temporary objects are not (necessarily) const. They're generally modifyable as long as they are alive.

Comment: Agreed. Compiler created temporary objects cannot be bound to non-const references and the original program tries to do that. It doesn’t make sense to modify compiler created temporary objects as they can die any moment.